# Not able to modify googlechart.html file from node-modules/node-red-contrib-googlechart

Tags: ibm-cloud, iot, node-modules, node-red

I deployed google chart node in my GIT repository in IBM BlueMix and able to generate graph too.

My problem is I am unable to see node-modules/node-red-contrib-googlechart folder where I can change the googlechart.html or googlechart.js. I want to change these files just to give a nice look and feel to my graphs with some background color as the default color is white

I need to go to my GIT repository through IBM BlueMix => GIT

Any pointers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is you do not edit a running app, you makes the changes, check then into git, then redeploy/restage the app.